# Modificar un elemento de una lista

Tags: python

Estoy creando una lista y quiero que si el usuario quiere, sea capaz de modificar un elemento de la lista. No se si hay una funcion que me ayude con eso o si necesito usar varias funciones para lograrlo

```
Lista = ["1", "2", "3", ...]

seguir = True
while seguir: 
  opcion = int(input("""
  Indique lo que desea realizar:
 \n 
  1) Mostrar los elementos de la lista 
  2) Editar un elemento


 if opcion == 1:
    for espacio in range(len(Lista)):
      print(f'\n {espacio} // {Lista[espacio]}')

 if opcion == 2:
  edit = input('Indique lo que quiera cambiar: ')
 #Aqui no se que poner
  print('Se ha cambiado exitosamente')
```

Comment: La lista se puede modificar accediendo a su posición, ejemplo ```lista[0] = 3``` y el valor de la lista cambiará, deberías pedirle al usuario que ingrese la posición que desa cambiar y el valor

Answer (score 0):

solo tenes q poner otro input preguntando que valor o POSICION queres cambiar de la lista, y luego buscas dentro de la lista por ese valor o posición, que seria la función findAndReplace :D

El código quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
Lista = ["1", "2", "3", "4","5"]

def findAndReplace(lista, itemAReemplazar, nuevoValor): 
    for index, item in enumerate(lista):
        if item == itemAReemplazar:
            lista[index] = nuevoValor

def mostrarMensajeInicio():
    opcion = int(input("""
      Indique lo que desea realizar:
        \n 
          1) Mostrar los elementos de la lista 
          2) Editar un elemento
      """))
    return opcion

seguir = True

while seguir:   
    opcion = mostrarMensajeInicio()
    if opcion == 1:
        for index in range(len(Lista)):
            print(f'\n Posicion {index} Valor:  {Lista[index]}')

    if opcion == 2:
        edit = input('Indique el Valor que quiere cambiar: ')
        if edit in Lista:
            newValue = input(f'Por que valor desea cambiar al numero {edit}: ')
            findAndReplace(Lista,edit,newValue)
            print('Se ha cambiado exitosamente')
        else :
            print('No se encuentra el numero en la Lista, intente nuevamente.')
```

Comment: me parece que hay muchas cosas que deberías explicar. No sólo copiar el código. Nedreus parece ser nuevo en python, no creo que sepa sobre funciones, así como tampoco creo que sepa que se puede acceder a una lista por medio de los índices y modificar los valores. Así que estaría bueno si puedes explicar mediante palabras lo que haz hecho, así Nedreus, o cualquier persona que lea esto, pueda comprenderlo fácil y rápidamente. Saludos.